# Django 1.7 and The Django book

Tags: django

I am gonna start my hands dirty in Django v 1.7. I wanted to know whether [Django Book](https://github.com/jacobian-archive/djangobook.com) will be a good place to start despite it supports older version? Or recommend me some other book

Comment: [Two Scoops](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-6) is a very good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like it says on the link

> This book was originally published by Apress in 2009 and covered
>   Django version 1.0. Since then it has languished and, in places, is
>   extremely out of date

I would definitely **not** recommend using this book to learn Django as many things have changed since version 1.0 (no class based views, no DB migration, etc.) When I tried learning Django I read part of this book and the current version of Django was 1.5. There were enough differences to make working through this book very difficult and frustrating, especially when you are a beginner. I would recommend reading through the Django Docs as they are actually really good and you can learn a lot from them. Otherwise find a book that is more recent (I wouldn't use resources meant for anything before 1.5 if you want to learn 1.7). I would recommend working through the tutorials until you feel comfortable then going through some book or more in depth resource. I found working through [Two Scoops of Django](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-6) to be very helpful as a beginner, despite it not being written for beginners, because I was forced to learn about many different simply to understand what they are talking about. Good luck learning django

Answer (score 1):

Take a look for Django Girls they do a good starting tutorial for Django 1.7. The big difference here is migrations you no longer need to install south into earlier version of Django